# HFS+ partition formatted

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, recovery, disk-format

few days ago I wanted to split partition but obviously I can't read and I chose "partitionDisk" option, basically I did:

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk1 GPT JHFS+ New 100g
```

That was a mistake. It didn't ask me anything about erasing data, but still its terminal so I don't blame it. 
Now I've got an empty partition, but I want to recover the old one.

Is there any way to to such thing? I tried with testdisk, but it's kinda hard to use this soft, tried also deeper search, I saw there about 100 of rows with multiple partitions, but couldn't preview any because of HFS+ I guess.

However I believe the last option would be to use Photorec and recover files one by one...

Is someone could help I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could email tech support for Photorec (and others) to see if they can recover from this particular situation. If they say no then your only recourse is a data recovery specialist like OnTrack.

Generally formatting/partitioning a drive does not wipe the data just the partition map and catalog, so it is possible that this might be recoverable.